# Consistency proof in topos logic

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory

Is the consistency of classical third-order arithmetic provable in the logic of a topos with natural numbers?

(My guess would be yes, but I haven't seen this anywhere.)

Edit: in the original version I used the name PA$_3$ as an abbreviation for classical third-order arithmetic, and comments have followed suit, but I've since learnt that this name refers to a different theory (the classical theory of third order functions).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $\Omega_{\neg\neg} = \{p \in \Omega \mid \neg\neg p \Rightarrow p\}$ be the object of $\neg\neg$-stable truth values, and let us write $P_{\neg\neg}(A) = {\Omega_{\neg\neg}}^A$ for the object of $\neg\neg$-stable subobjects of $A$. Observe that $\Omega_{\neg\neg}$ is a complete Boolean algebra, and this fact can be shown in the internal logic of a topos.

Now, it seems to me that one can build a model of $\mathsf{PA}_n$ for each $n$, by interpreting its logic in $\Omega_{\neg\neg}$, and the (higher-order) predicates as elements of the iterates of the $\neg\neg$-powersets ${P_{\neg\neg}}^k(\mathbb{N})$.

**Supplemental:** I initially claimed we can have a model of $\mathsf{PA}_\infty$, but Paul pointed out I was overstating the case. Indeed, to have a model of $\mathsf{PA}_\infty$ we would need a single object that encompasses all finite iterates $\neg\neg$-powersets ${P_{\neg\neg}}^k(\mathbb{N})$ at once, says something like $\coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {P_{\neg\neg}}^k(\mathbb{N})$. However, in an elementary topos such an object need not exist. A counter-model is the set $V_{\omega + \omega}$ of sets of rank below $\omega + \omega$.

Comment: [Deleted earlier comment - I hadn't read your message carefully.]

Comment: Great answer, Andrej, but I think you slightly overstated.  What this shows is that, for each $n \in \nats$, topos-with-nno logic can build a model of PA$_{n+1}$.  I've edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Another way to see this answer is: $HOL_N$ (classical higher-order logic with NNO; the logic of a Boolean topos with NMO) clearly proves the consistency of each $PA_n$. But $HOL_N$ translates into $IHOL_N$ via the double-negation translation.

Comment: \nats should be $\mathbb{N}$ in my comment.

Comment: @PaulBlainLevy: `\nat` is self-explanatory, I wouldn't worry about it. But to explain what your comment is about, I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks!  I have accordingly removed the supplement to my question.  It claimed that Bounded Zermelo is conservative over PA$_{\omega}$, and I'm not entirely sure of this, though it does seem plausible.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine is there a reference for that double-negation translation?  So that I can refer to it without having to write it out.

Comment: @PaulBlainLevy: off the top of my head, I’m not sure of a reference that gives it syntactically — my first hope was Lambek & Scott, but I can’t find it there.  Mac Lane and Moerdijk  Theorem VI.1.3 shows that “in any topos, the subtopos of $\lnot \lnot$-sheaves is Boolean”, which directly implies the syntactic translation.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine  I've found a reference,  Troelstra and van Dalen "Constructivism in Mathematics, an introduction", Volume 1, Chapter 3, Section 9.3.  I should have searched before asking you!